# Strange behavior in jQuery loop with arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am having an issue with the following code:

```
var samount = [{value:100, name:'USD'},
             {value:200, name:'USD'},
             {value:100, name:'USD'}];
var object1 = new Array;
objects1 = samount;
var categories1 = new Array();
var groupedObjects1 = [];
var output1 = '';
var i = 0;

console.log(samount);

_.each(objects1,function(obj){
    var existingObj;

    if($.inArray(obj.currency,categories1) >= 0) {
        existingObj = _.find(objects1,function(o){return o.currency === obj.currency;});
        existingObj.value += obj.value;
    } else {
        groupedObjects1[i] = obj;
        categories1[i] = obj.currency;
        i++;
    }
});

console.log(samount);
console.log(groupedObjects1);
```

The problem is that I do not want that **samount** variable to change after looping, so I have done this:

```
var object1 = new Array;
objects1 = samount;
```

The goal of this script is to sum up all values from the same currencies, but still to not mess with the initial array.
But it still changes the initial Array. Could anyone help me with this error?

Comment: In javascript, assigning another variable to a target object or array does not create a copy of the target, it points the new variable to the existing object.

Comment: So, a fix arround? For preventing it?

Comment: Create a copy of the array using one of the techniques below, I recommend adeneo's .slice technique as it does not rely on any libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the array with slice

```
var objects1 = samount.slice(0);
```

Arrays and object are passed by "reference" (not really, but doesn't matter here), so when assigning an array to a new variable, all you get is a reference to the same array, not a new array.

Comment: No, the array is copied ok, the problem is that it is changing after the loop, even if I do not use it

Comment: @rosuandreimihai - how is it "copied ok" when you're not copying it. `objects1 = samount` does not a new array make.

Answer (score 2):

You need to deep copy the initial array instead of affecting it.

```
var samount = [{value:100, name:'USD'},
             {value:200, name:'USD'},
             {value:100, name:'USD'}];
var object1  = $.extend(true, [], samount);
```

You were doing an affectation (i.e. 2 variables pointing to the same object) where you needed a copy (2 variables pointing to 2 different objects)

Comment: Perfect, didn;t knew that an variable could only point to another when when doing a copy. Thank you for this simple answer!

Comment: It's not about pointing or not to a variable. You were doing an affectation (i.e. 2 variables pointing to the same object) where you needed a copy (2 variables pointing to 2 different objects)

Comment: Now I am aware of the logic, so thanck you again, you have made me aware of some mistakes in my algorithms

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not creating a copy with

```
objects1 = samount
```

In most OO languages, you can only copy primitive types so int, strings characters etc, but not objects.

This is somewhat similar in javascript in the sense that {} is an object, same as Array or [].

So if you want to copy an object you'd have to iterate over every element of that object till you find an primitive type. This can be tedious and quite hard even (http://andrewdupont.net/2009/08/28/deep-extending-objects-in-javascript/)  this is called a deep copy.

But in this case a shallow copy (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is enough

```
var objects1 = samount.slice(0);
```